# Features Implementation on Asp.net boilerplate (abp)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, boilerplate

I want to know how I can implement an `AppFeature` in ASP.NET Boilerplate?

So far I have added an `AppFeatures` class and initialized an `AppFeatureProvider` in my project's `CoreModule`.

However when I log into the app, it's not working according to my database records.

Is there anybody that can help in this matter?

Comment: Not working in what way?

Comment: "...it's not working:..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: i think asp.net boilerplate user authorization not connecting to AppFeature entity in database. and when you change the value field of feature true/false its not have any difference in the application behavior.

Comment: Well, did you use `RequiresFeature` attribute? Provide relevant code.